# Server 2008 unresponsive after SP2 install

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a dev server that has an exact image of a production web server. The prod server only has SP1 installed on it. When I first fired up the dev box, the first thing I did was install SP2, and let it be. Almost every morning when I came in, the server was unusable. It would respond to ping, but RDP and the web site running on it were down. On the screen the screen saver was bouncing around, so it wasn't hard locked. But it was unresponsive to keyboard and mouse. So now I have to hard shut it down, but when it comes back up, the only thing in the event viewer is the unexpected shutdown, nothing else.

I've since taken a fresh image of my prod box and put it on the dev server, and not installed SP2, and the dev box is humming along perfectly. I should also note that this is Server2k8 Web, 64bit

Has anyone else seen anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should note that this was resolved. The dev box had a failing hard drive, and apparently SP2 was causing BSOD after being installed. The drive finally started clicking and died. After a fresh imaging with a copy of the production server, SP2 was installed, and has been good since.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to rerun the SP2 Upgrade ont he Dev-machine and really closely read the appropriate logs. If there is nothing to find, try disabling all running services (all but the standard services of course) like IIS and reenable them day by day to find out what is causing the error. Finding a way to provoke the semi-freeze would of course be helpful.